# Is sum of dimension of all eigen spaces smaller or equal to dimension of range T

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question is:

$T \in L(V)$; $T$ is an operator over vector space $V$ and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m$ are unique eigen values of $T$ which none of the $\lambda_i$ values is $0$. Prove the inequality below:

$$\dim E(\lambda_1,T)+\cdots+\dim E(\lambda_m,T) ≤ \dim \textrm{range}(T)$$

where $E(\lambda_i,T)$ is an eigen space of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda_i$
and $1 \leq i \leq m$

this is what I did so far:
$E(\lambda_i,T)$ makes a vector space so it so has dimensions and if $E(\lambda_i,T)$ and $E(\lambda_j,T)$ exist such that they have same basis , then the inequality is wrong, but as said in the question this won't happen, because $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$ are different eigen values so it makes different basis on $E(\lambda_i,T)$ and $E(\lambda_j,T)$.

I don't know if I'm right so far and if it is how to expand this to prove the inequation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. Notice I edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. I edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thanks for the advices. I was new and didn't know how to do things that are done here:)  I added the things I've done so far. If you could help me out solving this I'd appreciate.

Comment: Formatting! Please use mathjax. I will not go through every edit you make and fix your formatting.

Comment: Please format **entire** mathematical expressions, not just part of them, with Mathjax. In particular, don't write `E($\lambda_i$, T)` (which results in "E($\lambda_i$, T)", but rather, just like when writing LaTeX, write `$E(\lambda_i, T)$` which results in a much nicer looking $E(\lambda_i, T)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\dim(V)=n$. The number of linearly independent eigenvectors for T, which is the $LHS$ of the inequality, can never exceed $n$.

$\dim E(\lambda_1,T)+\cdots+\dim E(\lambda_m,T)  \leq n$

Let $N(T),R(T)$ denote the null space and range space of $T$ respectively.

Then by the rank-nullity dimension theorem, $\dim(N(T))+\dim(R(T))=n$

$\dim(N(T))$ is the number of independent eigenvectors for $T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$, which is $0$ according to the question.

So, $\dim E(\lambda_1,T)+\cdots+\dim E(\lambda_m,T) \leq n=\dim(R(T))$

Answer (score 0):

You are right so far. What you can do now is take all the basis vectors of the eigenspaces, and prove that they form a basis of a *subspace* of $\mathrm{range}(T)$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you obtain $range(T)$ here?

Comment: @user600016 You don't need to obtain it. To prove that $B$ is a basis of a subspace of $X$, then all you need to do is prove that each $b\in B$ is an element of $X$. You don't need to know all about $X$ to do that.